# ¿ Como puedo eliminar un documento en firebase si tiene una llave automatica?

Tags: android

Es para eliminar un documente que tiene su llave automática

```
databaseReference.child(RecLicence).child("Carrera").child(databaseReference.push().getKey()).removeValue();
```

Comment: Hola, pero como llegaste hasta el documento? porque creo que podrias obtener su referencia y desde alli eliminarlo. Ademas, lo que estas haciendo esta mal porque estas obteniendo una referencia que no existe porque databaseReference.push().getKey() obtiene una nueva Key generada automaticamente porque lo que estas eliminando algo que todavia no existe.

Comment: Lo que necesito hacer es eliminar un documento que tiene una lleve generada automáticamente como accedo a ese documento.